# How can a sine wave or cosine wave represent a transverse wave?

Tags: acoustics, fourier-transform

I assume a transverse wave such as the sound waves can be represented as longitudinal waves. Although highly intuitive is there a function that normally converts one to the other or can we just assume that whatever works for one will also work for the other such as the application of Fourier analysis to longitudinal waves.

Comment: Sound waves are longitudinal, but this makes no difference to the applicability of Fourier techniques.

Comment: After posting the question....long behold.....www.zonalandeducation.com/mstm/physics/waves/TransLongWaves/TransAndLongWave1.htm. This is a pictorial sketch "proof" so my question asks if this is sufficient or is there in reality a mathematical conversion of this lurking in the background.

Answer (score 2):

Fourier analysis is a mathematical technique applicable to any periodic phenomena, with "periodic" understood in its broadest sense.  Indeed Fourier analysis can be used to solve certain types of differential equations applicable to a variety of phenomena, related or unrelated to waves, although sound is a particularly pregnant example.  Other examples include signal analysis, or various problems of heat propagation in material.

Comment: +1 And when you learn about the subject, it is in 1 D values.